# Download data ERA5 with R. Problem module 'requests' from python

Tags: r, installation, conda, era5

I have done a small program based on the work done by Dominic Royé to download data from ERA5 in R. And it was working perfectly a few months ago. I wanted to rerun it now. But there is a problem with the module 'requests'.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(ncdf4)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf) 
library(raster)
library(terra)
library("mapSpain")
library(reticulate)
library(ncdf4)
library(parallel)

#-------------------LOCAL----------------------------#
#install the CDS API
conda_install("r-reticulate","cdsapi", pip=TRUE)#import python CDS-API
cdsapi <- import("cdsapi")
```

but now when I run the import("cdsapi") it gives me this error:
*Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'*

What it is the problem?